# Getting CPU 100 percent when I am trying to downloading CSV in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, csv

I am getting CPU performance issue on server when I am trying to download CSV in my project, CPU goes 100% but SQL returns the response within 1 minute. In the CSV we are writing around 600K records for one user it is working fine but for concurrent users we are getting this issue.

**Environment**

- Spring 4.2.5
- Tomcat 7/8 (RAM 2GB Allocated)
- MySQL 5.0.5
- Java 1.7

Here is the Spring Controller code:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="csvData")
public void getCSVData(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value="param1", required=false) String param1,
        @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) String param2,
        @RequestParam(value="param3", required=false) String param3) throws IOException{

    List<Log> logs =   service.getCSVData(param1,param2,param3);

    response.setHeader("Content-type","application/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=logData.csv");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    out.println("Field1,Field2,Field3,.......,Field16");
    for(Log row: logs){
            out.println(row.getField1()+","+row.getField2()+","+row.getField3()+"......"+row.getField16());
    }
    out.flush();  
    out.close(); 
}}
```

**Persistance Code:-** I am using spring JDBCTemplate

```
@Override
public List<Log> getCSVLog(String param1,String param2,String param3) {
    String sql =SqlConstants.CSV_ACTIVITY.toString();
    List<Log> csvLog = JdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{param1, param2, param3},
            new RowMapper<Log>() {
                @Override
                public Log mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                throws SQLException {
                    Log log = new Log();
                    log.getField1(rs.getInt("field1"));
                    log.getField2(rs.getString("field2"));
                    log.getField3(rs.getString("field3"));
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    log.getField16(rs.getString("field16"));
                    }
                 return log;
                }
            });

    return csvLog;
}
```

Comment: You should provide your persistance code -  if SQL returns the responce after 1 minute I believe that bottleneck is in the database, not in Java

Comment: Cootri, After using StringBuilder I am  getting HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: If you managed to narrow down the problem to the DB call then the code you included is irrelevant. There's nothing that would help to diagnose the problem in the question in its current shape.

Comment: @NikhilGupta, Are you using SAX Parser or DOM Parser? Please use SAX Parser.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I am using JDBCTemplate and getting ResultSet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be specific on what you meant by "100% CPU usage" whether it's the Java process or MySQL server. As you have got 600K records, trying to load everything in to memory would easily end up in `OutOfMemoryError`. Given that this works for one user means that you've got enough heap space to process this number of records for just one user and symptoms surface when there are multiple users trying to use the same service.

First issue I can see in your posted code is that you try to load everything into one big list and the size of the list varies based on the content of the `Log` class. Using a list like this also means that you have to have enough memory to process JDBC result set and generate new list of `Log` instances. This can be a major problem with a growing number of users. This type of short-lived objects will cause frequent GC and once GC cannot keep up with the amount of garbage being collected it fails obviously. To solve this major issue my suggestion is to use [ScrollableResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/resltset.htm#i1022314). Additionally you can make this result set read-only, for example below is code fragment for creating a scrollable result set. Take a look at the documentation for how to use it.

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Above option is suitable if you're using pure JDBC or SpringJDBC template. If Hibernate is already used in your project you can still achieve the same this with the below code fragment. Again please check the documentation for more information and you have a different JPA provider.

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryStr).setCacheable(false).setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE).setReadOnly(true);
query.setParameter(query_param_key, query_paramter_value);
ScrollableResults resultSet = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

This way you're not loading all the records to Java process in one go, instead you they're loaded on demand and will have small memory footprint at any given time. Note that JDBC connection will be open until you're done with processing the entire record set. This also means that your DB connection pool can be exhausted if many users are going to download CSV files from this endpoint. You need to take measures to overcome this problem (i.e use of an API manager to rate limit the calls to this endpoint, reading from a read-replica or whatever viable option).

My other suggestion is to stream data which you have already done, so that any records fetched from the DB are processed and sent to client before the next set of records are processed. Again I would suggest you to use a CSV library such as [SuperCSV](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html) to handle this as these libraries are designed to handle a good load of data.

Please note that **this answer may not exactly answer your question as you haven't provided necessary parts of your source such as how to retrieve data from DB but will give the right direction to solve this issue**

Comment: Bunti, Thanks for update please see my Persistance Code

Comment: @NikhilGupta your options as I can see are to use 1.(As I have shown above) a [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object to get a connection and set the [fetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) to Integer.MIN_VALUE as a hint to JDBC driver to use streaming of records instead of fetching a set of records of some size. 2.) is to subclass JDBCTemplate or NamedParamterJDBCTemplate and override `getPreparedStatementCreator` method to provide your own PreparedStatement that will stream records.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in loading all data on application server from database at once, try to run query with `limit` and `offset` parameters (with mandatory `order by`), push loaded records to client and load next part of data with different `offset`. It help you decrease memory footprint and will not required keep connection to database open all the time. Of course, database will loaded a bit more, but maybe whole situation will better. Try different `limit` values, for example 5K-50K and monitor cpu usage - on both app server and database.

If you can allow keep many open connection to database @Bunti answer is very good.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html